# How can I combine a kinship matrix with subset individuals when using rvtests?

Tags: microarray

I've been processing data for a consortium project that uses the [rvtests](https://github.com/zhanxw/rvtests) toolkit. Our data analysis process uses a kinship matrix and the calculation of inverse-normalised transformed statistics after covariate adjustment (for 1kG-imputed data from a SNPchip). One of the operations we have been asked to do is to analyse males and females separately for a number of different phenotypes.

Here's an example of the command line that I'm running:

```
rvtest --inVcf chr${ch}.imputed.poly.vcf.gz \
 --pheno ../scripts/phenotypes.raw.2017-May-01.ped \
 --pheno-name ${traitName} \
 --out rv_results/${traitName}_FEMALE_chr${ch} \
 --kinship kinship_matrix.kinship \
 --meta score,cov[windowSize=500000] \
 --peopleIncludeFile ../scripts/female.iids.txt \
 --covar ../scripts/covar.2017-May-11.ped \
 --covar-name ${covs} --useResidualAsPhenotype --dosage DS
```

Unfortunately, the kinship matrix doesn't interact well with the `--peopleinclude` parameter. When I run this, the program complains about unexpected columns in the kinship matrix (starting at one column greater than the number of females in the dataset). I suspect what is happening is that rvtests is assuming that the kinship matrix applies to the sample set *after* filtering, rather than applying to the total sample set. This sets off a few warning bells in my head, because it means that rvtest is probably ignoring the column/row labels in the kinship matrix that it has generated.

How can I work around this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adam Locke (a collaborator of this project) suggests that removing covariate information for the unselected individuals (i.e. setting it to NA) works around this problem:

> I believe the problem is that he is using a pre-computed kinship matrix including both males and females, and when using the “—peopleIncludeFile” it can’t properly select the right people from the kinship matrix. I don’t know that others have tried to do analysis this way. An alternative, that I think has worked for others, is to generate phenotype variables that have values only for males or females (so, e.g., BMI, BMI_females, BMI_males). For whatever reason, this appears to correctly only use the and select the samples desired without the kinship matrix.

Presumably a kinship matrix that is generated for just the subset individuals will work as well, although I don't like the idea that rvtests isn't able to do a label lookup on the kinship matrix to find the correct individuals.